# Difficulty understanding step in proof from Morgan's "Geometric Measure Theory"

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

Context: Towards the end of the proof that the n dimensional Hausdorff measure is equal to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, there is an inequality I do not understand. $S$ is a ball in a covering of a set $A$.

Morgan claims that
$$
\mathscr{L}(S)\geq \alpha_n(\frac{diam(S)}{2})^n
$$
where diameter is defined as usual as the supremum of all distances between elements in the set and $\alpha_n$ is the Lebesgue n-volume of the unit ball.

I think this is probably just a basic fact from Lebesgue theory that I never learned. If it is not, I can provide more context.

Comment: It's a ball with _diameter_ $\operatorname{diam} (S)$. Its radius is $\dfrac{\operatorname{diam}(S)}{2}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think I was confused, I am going to delete my justification

Comment: Is $\alpha_n$ the Lebesgue measure of the unit ball, or the Hausdorff measure? [Yes, they are equal - if we normalise the Hausdorff measure accordingly - but we can't use that fact yet, since that's what is to be proved.]

Comment: @DanielFischer it is the Lebesgue measure

Comment: By the change-of-variables formula we have $\mathscr{L}(c\cdot M) = \lvert c\rvert^n \cdot \mathscr{L}(M)$ for every Lebesgue measurable $M$. Since $S$ is a translate of $c\cdot B$ where $B$ is the unit ball and $c = \dfrac{\operatorname{diam}(S)}{2} \geqslant 0$, the inequality follows [actually, equality].

Comment: @DanielFischer That was immensely helpful. I had a feeling it was something simple I was missing. Please feel free to add this as an answer; I will accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change-of-variables formula shows that for every Lebesgue measurable $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\mathscr{L}(c\cdot M) = \lvert c\rvert^n\cdot \mathscr{L}(M)$. Using also the translation invariance, it follows that the Lebesgue measure of a ball of radius $r$ is $\alpha_n r^n$. So we have not only the inequality, in fact the equality

$$\mathscr{L}(S) = \alpha_n\biggl(\frac{\operatorname{diam}(S)}{2}\biggr)^n.$$